# How to activate syntax highlighting for multiple references in TexStudio?

Tags: biblatex, highlighting, texstudio

I want to enable highlighting for multiple references command `\parencites {}` of Biblatex package the same as of a similar command for one reference `\parencite {}` using TexStudio editor.

The image below shows that when `\parencite {}` is used the reference key would be conveniently highlighted based on the syntax highlighting scheme setup in TexStudio, light green in this case. However, this was disabled and defaulted to black when I used its cousin command `\parencites {}` for multiple references (underlined with black).
How to get the multiple references also light green highlighted in TexStudio?

[image]

**Note**
Feature request for TexStudio was added under ticket:
 `#694 Syntax highlighting will break if \parencites{<label>}`

Comment: Which version of TXS are you using?

Comment: TeXstudio 2.6.4 (hg 4040:c545be7ff950) - win7-32bit

Comment: I recommend that you update to version 2.7.0. It should be fixed there.

Comment: I updated to 2.7.0, I confirm the issue was solved for \parencites, but other new issues popped up. Now \gls{<labels>} are highlighted, whereas \glspl{<label>} not. In addition, it tell me that all gls refs are missing while they do exist. Any idea how to set highlighting off for gls commands or other advice may be?

Comment: I ended up with a workaround, but not elegant for TexStudio. I set black color syntax highlighting for all missing references.

Comment: The \gls highlighting is an error in a user-contributed cwl file for glossaries. Will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: thanks, I hope also this would be solved along with other other variants of gls command, like Gls, Glspl, etc.

Comment: @TimHoffmann, I just noticed that `\cref` when using multiple labels also is not highlighted, you might kindly consider this for the next release of TXS.

Comment: Commands containing multiple references are currently not supported by our parser - and won't be until a major rewrite of it, which we won't have time to in the near future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a limitation of an external programme (namely TeXStudio) this is really rather a feature request.